# Make accessors private in child class

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Let's say I have a class A with public accessors:

```
class Test_A
    attr_accessor :a
    attr_accessor :b
    attr_accessor :c
end
```

Its instance variables would be accessible, e.g:

```
test = Test_A.new()
test.a = 3
```

I want to inherit the class Test_A in Test_B:

```
class Test_B < Test_A
    private
        attr_accessor :d
        attr_accessor :e
end
```

The instance variables inherited from Test_A are now also accessible in Test_B:

```
test = Test_B.new()
test.a = 3
```

I want to achieve the following:

- If I create an instance of Test_A, all instance variables shall be accessible from outside.
- If I create an instance of Test_B, I want all inherited instance variables and methods from Test_A to be private.

Is there any way to mark the methods and instance variables as private in the child class?

Just some background: I am developing a rake based buildsystem: There are many "recipe" files which will define software sources like:

```
sw_pkg.srcs = "blabla.c blabla2.c"
sw_pkg.incs = "blabla.h blabla2.h"
```

"sw_pkg" could be an instance of class A. All accessors must be accessible from outside, within these recipes.

Within the Rakefile I scan all these recipes and use class B which defines all methods for building the sources defined in the recipe file. However, within the Rakefile I don't want to modify anything of the accessors derived from class A from the "outside"

Comment: What do you mean by "Let's say I have a class A"? How is class A relevant?

Comment: Another inaccuracy: you can't access instance variables from the outside, you access methods. (`a` and `a=` are methods whereas `@a` is an instance variable)

Comment: I am developing a rake based build system. There will be let's call it recipe files which will be scanned within the Rakefile. Within the recipe i use class A to define all software sources and so on. All instance variables shall be public accessible within these recipes. Within the buildsystem internally i use class B to handle all build tasks and it shall not be possible to access those instance variables from outside.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, Stefan

Comment: The first question here is "why", not "how". :-)

Comment: @franz86 maybe I'm wrong but it sounds like `A` and `B` don't really have an [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) could be more appropriate.

Comment: @Stefan, probably you are right, I am sure there a better ways to implement this, however I am a noob in ruby and don't know how :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

```
class Test_A
  attr_accessor :d, :e
end

class Test_B < Test_A
  private :d, :d=, :e, :e=
end
```

But I think that having private accessors is useless because if you can omit the receiver, then you are in the context of `Test_B` instance, where you can directly access the instance variables without using the accessors.

Comment: Thanks sawa, it works, but it seems a little ugly to me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: In what sense is it ugly? What do you expect? And what do you think about what I wrote?

Comment: I thought there is a way to make the inherited class private, as is, without listing all accessors again in the child class.

Comment: @franz86 just the "accessor methods" or all methods?

Comment: It would be sufficient if just the "accessor methods" would be private

Comment: @franz86 unfortunately, there is no easy way to get the accessors afterwards. You could define an array in `Test_A`, e.g. `ATTRS = [:a, :b, :c]`, define the attributes via `attr_accessor *ATTRS` and use the same array (inheritance, yay!) to declare them private in `Test_B`, i.e. `private *ATTRS.flat_map { |a| [a, :"#{a}="] }`

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, stefan. I thought there would be an easier way. I think my usecase is really special and is not really needed in a "normal" ruby application.